# Автозаполнение директорий

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня есть следующий исходный путь:

2022:

- 1 квартал
- 2 квартал
- 3 квартал
- 4 квартал

Я хочу внутрь каждого поместить, например txt файл с названием каждого квартала.

Дошел только до того что могу создать в текущей директории 4 текстовых файла и написать внутри название каждого квартала:

```
import os

path_1= r'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog3\2022'

a = os.listdir(path_1)

for i in a:
    file_name = '{}.txt'.format(i)
    with open(file_name,'w') as f:
        f.write(i)
```

Что нужно добавить в цикл, чтобы эти файлы помещались внутрь директории, а не в исходную добавлялся?

Заранее, благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

```
import os

path_1= r'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog3\2022'

for path in os.listdir(path_1):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path_1, path)):
        file_path = os.path.join(path_1, path, path+'.txt')
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write('hello')
```

Comment: чуть чуть меня опередили. Спасибо за наводку в file_path `path+'txt'` мне именно этого кусочка не хватало!

Comment: А если задача усложняется https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433062/автозаполнение-директорий-на-нескольких-уровнях

Comment: @convair36 `os.walk`

Answer (score 0):

Немножко покопавшись по итогу получилось так:

```
path_1= r'C:\Users\МВИДЕО\progs\prog3\2022'

a = os.listdir(path_1)

for i in a:
    file_name = '{}.txt'.format(i)
    path_2 = os.path.join(path_1,i,i+'.txt')
    with open(path_2,'w') as f:
        f.write(i)
```